# Are these two expressions equivalent if x and y are fuzzy?

Tags: fuzzy-logic, interdefinability

Consider two variables of the same sort, from a domain of “qualities”.

For example, *x* could be a fuzzily defined concept like “happiness”.

In this domain of discourse, I claim the following:

1. ¬(∀x∃y(◇(x ≠ y)) : not every x is possibly numerically distinct from some y

This says that it is not the case that, for any such quality, there is some other corresponding quality, which it is possible that it is not equal to.

In my system of logic, I would like to be able to commute the negativity operator with the quantifiers, like so:

2. ∀x∃y(¬◇(x ≠ y)) : every x is necessarily numerically identical to some y

This says that for any such quality, there is some corresponding quality, for which it is impossible that the two qualities are inequivalent.

In other words, every quality necessarily has a synonym - and in this system, equality is not the same as identity. The qualities are distinct, yet equivalent, in this logic.

On the other hand, (2) may be (trivially) true by the reflexive property of my equality predicate: for all x, x = x.

I would like to know what system of formal logic would allow me to prove or disprove (2) from (1).

Here’s my motivation:

If some happiness exists, even when we are discontent, then there is no mutual exclusivity between “discontentment” and “happiness”, as states; both may be present at the same time. This statement may be reformulated with a negation: it is not the case that there is a mutual exclusivity between “happiness” and “contentment”, as states, either.

Ergo, you cannot clearly individuate happiness from contentment, even though they are not the same thing up to identity.

To give another example; I think “the present” and “consciousness” are vague. Then according to the premise, there is no present without consciousness.

In other words, I am trying to prove that if a semantic concept is not strictly defined in terms of semantic primitives which are mutually exclusive from some other semantic concept, then it shows how concepts are interdependent, interdefined, and cannot be present or exist without each other’s existence or presence.

Comment: I don't have a problem with you. We are trying to explain how this use of formal expression does not clarify but obscure your question. Very honestly and sorry if this sounds a bit mean, for someone who did formal logic your second sentence sounds like: "If 4 is sometimes but 6 is always does 4+6 = 8 and so 6 = 8 ?"

Comment: oh ok so what do you mean by that @Johan that the two formulas do not entail each other for vague terms or that the "vague term" is not defined or that it cannot be used with the formulas?

Comment: is the problem that you can only use modal logic with predicates and it's useless trying to clarify imprecise terms. it just doesn't make sense to say that it is not possible to be both unhappy and content @Johan except in natual language?

Comment: @Conifold “*You quantify over x and y, so 'x' and 'y' are variables and cannot be any "terms"*”. I thought a variable was defined as a “term”, and a formula is when you quantify a predicate over a term.

Comment: “*'not y' is ungrammatical, negation cannot be attached to variables*” Maybe conventionally, but since they are trying to express an idea in a formal system, we could enable such a syntax. We could define a function “not” on terms, with a corresponding meaning in the domain of discourse (for example, antonymy). This would be like defining set operations in FOL like intersection, complement, etc.

Comment: @JuliusHamilton This post underwent 11 edits, so I do not know what goes on there now. "Term" was originally used as a synonym of "concept", not for a well-formed expression in a formal system. 'Negation' defined on the domain of discourse consisting of concepts is fine, but it better be distinguished from logical negation ¬. It will be part of internal algebra which has to be additionally axiomatized. I do not see the point of doing that when predicates already stand for concepts. Possibly, OP wanted to quantify over predicates, but then they conflated negations at different levels.

Comment: are you trying to help me answer my question @Conifold ?

Comment: Your 2 does not follow from 1. When you distribute negation into a formula with quantifiers, you have to invert the quantifiers. Instead of 2 you would get ∃x∀y(¬◇(x ≠ y)). I doubt whether these formulas really express what you want. If you wish to quantify over properties you should use second order logic and use a predicate complementation operator instead of propositional negation.

Comment: i think they do express what i want, which would be clearer if my edit was accepted @Bumble i am unsure whether 1 implies 2 for vague terms. idk why everyone thinks i need to use predicate logic, and it would be appreciated if someone did say why

Comment: I like fuzzy logic, fuzzy logic makes sense. But I don't like the possibility operator. It's only circularly interpretable by reference to an undefined collection of "possible worlds" which we have no reason to think exist. It very poorly models use of the word "possible" in natural language, which has more to do with degrees of belief, i.e. we say something is possible if we at that time assign some significantly nonzero degree of belief to it.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll try to help by giving some tangentially related formalizations, which won’t necessarily answer the question, but maybe help others by giving them something to build on.

This much seems clear to me:

1. You want to model concepts formally (this can be called “formal concept analysis”); if you need a semantics for these expressions, I recommend you consider a system built out of semantic primitives. That could help you show concretely how two concepts have some inseparability.
2. You have your own semantic predicate, “=“, which is not the same as identity. One way you can say this is, equality does not equal equivalence.
3. Your goal is to prove unavoidable interdefinability as a universal property of concepts.
4. You tried to do this with a certain expression of modal logic. As is commonly called the “XY-problem” on Stack Exchange, your question asked for a solution to a sub-problem you devised as an attempted solution for your main problem.

It is easier to disentangle ourselves from the attempted solution, and focus on the main problem, from scratch.

###### Here is just some thought to help give you a platform to reformulate the idea.

1. You tried to express interdefinability or the inseparability of concepts roughly as, “for each concept *x*, there exists some other concept *y*, such that, *x* necessarily equals *y*.
2. The use of a modal operator may be deadweight. Let’s pause for a moment to think about why modal operators tend to be useful or necessary to express something that you can’t, without them.
3. A modal operator can be thought of as a semantic predicate on the concept of “truth” itself. Normal logical connectives like “and” take formulas as arguments and assign a truth value to that tuple of inputs. Conceptually, you could argue that logical connectives “syntactically rearrange” expressions prior to their truth-evaluation. But modal operators actually expand the semantic range of the truth-domain, allowing one to express new flavors of truth, like “possibly true”, and others.
4. Let’s make the problem simpler by removing the use of modal operators until we see a definite need for them.
5. Try to define a semantics for your equality predicate, “=“. For example, consider a concept to be an element in a cumulative hierarchy of sets, whose initial set is a set of semantic primitives.
6. S = {c1, c2, c3,…, c(n)}
7. G(0) = S
8. G(a + 1) = P(a), where P(x) represents taking the power set operation on a set x.

You need to find a way to claim two concepts, even if conceived of as opposites, can be “co-present”, which you use to claim that they are not causally mutually exclusive, which you use to claim that therefore every concept has some distinct concept which is not causally independent, I think.

That’s all I have for now. Sorry.

Comment: i am a bit confused, but thanks for trying with me!

Answer (score 0):

The two expressions were

1. ¬(∀x∃y(◇(x ≠ y)) : not every x is possibly numerically distinct from some y
2. ∀x∃y(¬◇(x ≠ y)) : every x is necessarily numerically identical to some y

I was trying to work out what it would mean if all y was identical to something vague, x, without reading anything; got a bit distracted from the above fornulas.

If every y has a non-zero (and non-one?) truth value for being identical to some x then all x elements have a non-zero truth value for being identical to some y, becasue if some x has a zero truth value for being identical to some y then some y has a zero truth value for being identical to some x.

Right?

Suppose that y is the time of birth and rebirth, and x is the vague present. Indeed, we might suppose that every rebirth occurs in a vague present: then every present has a non-zero truth value for being identical to the time of some rebirth.

Suppose that my death, the end of rebirth, is sharp, that there is a crisp boundary between life and death. It definitely seems to me to make sense to think that, despite the time of rebirth being identical to vague present times (as bard pointed out to me, a sharp, 13ml, and vague, a bit, measure of something can be identical).

Supposing that every future time will be present, and it is vague as to whether rebirth occurs then, then surely there is no crisp boundary to rebirth, no death.

I find vagueness difficult to think about, but that's how I am thinking about that for now.

Comment: you get the point. fully worked out, entirely stupid